# shopping cart in local storage connecting with mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am currently working on building an E-commerce website and I am using HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP and SQL. I have created my database for each product(ID, price, image, name). I defined my shopping cart as a Javascript array with product ID's. This array is stored in local storage. I can now add items and delete items from my local storage array. Eventually, I want to send the order information (product_ID, quantity and customer_ID) to my SQL database. So in short my question is, is this an efficient way to build a shopping cart? that is storing user information in local storage and send that information to SQL server when purchased. Is it even possible to use local storage array in php code?

This is my first time making a website. If there is a better and efficient way I would like to know!

Thank you.

This is my java script functions for adding to cart and deleting from cart.

```
// function that adds an item in shopping cart
function addToCartClicked(itemId) {
  // initialize shopping cart array
  if (localStorage.getItem("cart") == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", "[]");
  }

  // get old data and add it to the new one
  var old_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  old_data.push(itemId);

  // save the new one
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(old_data));
}

// delete button
function deleteButton(itemId) {
  var buttonClicked = event.target;
  buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  // deletes this from localStorage

  for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    console.log("hello?")
    if (itemId == cart[i]) {
      console.log(cart);
      cart.splice(i,1);
      localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));
      console.log(cart);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```